# MQTT / Moscapsule / Swift : how to pass data from a topic to a label and autoupdate whenever a message is published to the topic

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mqtt, mosquitto

OK, first, I am new to swift / xcode.  This is my first question to stackoverflow.  hoping someone can help me out here, and that this might be useful to some others.

I am writing a little iphone app to connect with my MQTT broker (Mosquitto, running on raspbian, which then talks to some other arduinos / devices.  this is not important)

The app has a button which publishes a message to a topic, and a label, which (SHOULD!) display the last message published to that topic, or any topic.  as soon as the message comes in from the broker.

I have gotten the app to subscribe to a topic and publish to a topic.   I can even get the button function to reset the label text to the last message published on that topic.

What I would like to do is get the label text to update every time that a message is published to a specified topic.

I have tried moving the line     `self.viewer.text = String(L)` from under the button function to inside     `mqttConfig.onMessageCallback`  thinking that this would reset the labels text every time the onMessageCallback function was called.  That seemed logical to me but does not work.  I think I am probably missing something conceptual here.

included is the code.

note: there is a variable L that I probably don't need, which I was using to try and pass the data in and out of functions.

note 2:  my approach as described above, that didn't work, was to move line 75, to line 52, right below .   `L = receivedMessage`

note 3: Xcode 9, Swift 3.2

```
        //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  092817app2
    //
    //  Created by ---- on 9/28/17.
    //  Copyright © 2017 ---. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit
    import Moscapsule


    let msg = "11111"
    let topic = "topic"
    var L = "0"





    class ViewController: UIViewController {


        //set MQTT client configuration
        let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "aaa", host: "192.168.0.19", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)

        // create new MQTT Connection
        var mqttClient: MQTTClient? = nil



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        mqttConfig.onPublishCallback = { messageId in
            print("published (msg id=\(messageId)))")
            }



        mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
            print("MQTT Message received: payload=\(mqttMessage.payloadString)")
            let receivedMessage = mqttMessage.payloadString!
            print("from server msg = \(receivedMessage)")

            let data = receivedMessage.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            print("xxxxxxx = \(data)")

            L = receivedMessage

            }

        mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(mqttConfig, connectImmediately: true)

        mqttClient?.subscribe("topic", qos: 0)
 }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBAction func on(_ sender: Any) {
        print("11111")
        mqttClient?.publish(string: "11111", topic: "topic", qos: 1, retain: false)

        self.viewer.text = String(L)

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var viewer: UILabel!



    }
```

Thanks very much for taking a look!

PS. maybe someone with a better reputation than me can start a tag Moscapsule.